# ReactNative - get data from promise (JSON)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch, async.js

I am able to fetched the JSON data and it now returns an array. How do I use the elements in the array in react native? Below is my attempt:

```
export default function display() {

const fetching = async() => ... //defines fetching() which returns the array

...

    return (
       <View>
           <Image 
                source = {{uri: 'http://imageURI.' + fetching().then((arr) =>  {return arr[0]}) + '.png'}}
                style = {{height: 50, width: 50, borderRadius: 50}} />
       </View>
    )

}
```

How can I access the elements in the array?

Comment: Could you post the full code of your `fetching` mehtod?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following.

You need to make your API call asynchronously, display something until you get the response and then update the state with retrieved data.

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {View, Image} from 'react-native'

const fetch = async () => {/* ASYNC LOGIC HERE*/};

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [uri, setUri] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch().then((arr) => {
      setUri(`http://imageURI.${arr[0]}.png`);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      {
        uri ? <Image source={{uri}} style={{height: 50, width: 50, borderRadius: 50}} /> : null
      }
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is really helpful, but I am quite new to RN, so may I ask when will the UseEffect actually run? Why when I console.log(uri) in the useEffect it gives null, but it works in the return statement below?

Comment: @cel-0207 the `useEffect` hook (see [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)) runs immediately after the component "mounts" (after elements with initial state have been added to the DOM) and then runs again on each render only if at least one of the variables in the dependencies array (secondo argument) changed.

Comment: @cel-0207 setting state (using `setUri` in this case) can sometimes happen asynchronously. When `useEffect` first runs you read `null` after calling `setUri` and maybe also immediately after. Once the state effectively changes, a re-render is triggered and you read the new value in the `return` statement.

Comment: @cel-0207 in this case, as the dependencies array is empty, `useEffect` will run only once!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with ernesto, I would just do all my logic in the fetching function and for me if you get an array it is for several elements so I would prepare that with a map method

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { View, Image } from "react-native";

const Display = () => {
 const [state, setState] = useState(null);

 const fetching = async () => {
  try {
   const response = await fetch("api.exemple");
   const imagesArray = await response.json();

   setState(imagesArray);
  } catch (error) {
   console.log(error);
  }
 };

 useEffect(() => {
  fetching();
 }, []);

 return (
  <View>
   {state &&
    state.map((fileName) => {
     const uri = `http://imageURI.${fileName}.png`;
     return (
      <Image
       source={{ uri }}
       style={{ height: 50, width: 50, borderRadius: 50 }}
      />
     );
    })}
   </View>
 );
};

export default Display;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, the map method is really necessary here :) !